T closed iff Cayley Transformation closed
Let $T$ be a hermitian (i.e:symmetric and densely defined) operator and $\lambda \in \mathbb C\backslash \mathbb R$. Then, we can define the Cayley transformation of $T$ as the map $ U_T=(T-\lambda 1)(T-\overline{\lambda}1)^{-1}$.

Proposition 13.3 (Schmudgen, Unbounded Self-adjoint
operators in Hilbert space). Here the author states (among other
results) that T is closed iff $U_T$ is closed.

The proof given is "We have that $T$ is closed iff $D(U_T)=R(T-\overline{\lambda}1)$"
The converse is okay, $T$ closed implies $U_T$ closed because we have a result (proposition 2.1 of the same book) which says "$T$ closed and $\lambda\in \pi(T)$ implies $R(T-\lambda 1)\subset \mathcal H$ is a closed subespace (here $\pi(T)$ is the set of regular points of $T$)".
I don't see why $D(U_T)=R(T-\overline{\lambda}1)$ implies $T$ closed if $U_T$ is closed.
I'm feeling there is a really obvious thing behind this, but I'm not seeing the point.
My idea at this point is the following: using both
$$ (a)\;\;{\|(T-\overline{\lambda}1)x\|}\geq \sqrt{2 \;Im(\lambda)}\;\|x\| \quad \text{and} \quad (b)\;\;\|Tx\|\leq \|(T-\overline{\lambda}1)x\|+ |\overline{\lambda}|\|x\|,$$
we have that $U_T$ closed implies every Cauchy sequence in $R(T-\overline{\lambda})$ is convergente, so by (a) every Cauchy sequence in $D(T)$ is convergente. Using this, by (b) every Cauchy sequence $(Tx_n)$ is convergente. This gives us $G(T)$ closed and then $T$ closed. Is this correct?

It looks like there is a typo for equation (b) at the start of your idea. You may want to double check that part.

It may be helpful to expand on the proof from the book in more detail. You can ignore certain implications if you are only interested in your main question, namely why $D(U_{T}) = R(T - \overline{\lambda}1)$ implies $T$ closed if $U_{T}$ is closed.
The proof in the book for Proposition 13.3(iii) is stated as follows. Note that the book is using $V_{T}$ for what you denote as $U_{T}$.

(iii): By Proposition 2.1, $T$ is closed if and only if $\mathcal{D}(V_{T}) = \mathcal{R}(T - \overline{\lambda} I)$ is closed in $\mathcal{H}$, or equivalently, the bounded operator $V_{T}$ is closed.

Two statements are made within the proof and are then combined to obtain the desired conclusion. Various definitions and results within the book will be used, so they are stated later on for readers who do not have access to the book.
The first statement is that $T$ is closed if and only if $\mathcal{R}(T - \overline{\lambda} I)$ is closed in $\mathcal{H}$. If $T$ is closed then $\mathcal{R}(T - \overline{\lambda} I)$ is closed in $\mathcal{H}$ by Proposition 2.1(iv). Conversely, if $\mathcal{R}(T - \overline{\lambda} I)$ is closed in $\mathcal{H}$ then by Proposition 2.1(i) the linear operator $T - \overline{\lambda}I$ has a bounded inverse $(T - \overline{\lambda} I)^{-1}$ defined on the Hilbert space $\mathcal{R}(T - \overline{\lambda}I)$. By the closed graph theorem $\mathcal{G}(T - \overline{\lambda}I)^{-1}$ is closed in $\mathcal{R}(T - \overline{\lambda} I) \times \mathcal{H}$. But $\mathcal{R}(T - \overline{\lambda}I ) \times \mathcal{H}$ is closed in $\mathcal{H} \times \mathcal{H}$ so $\mathcal{G}(T - \overline{\lambda}I)^{-1}$ is closed in $\mathcal{H} \times \mathcal{H}$. Define $\phi :\mathcal{H} \times \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H} \times \mathcal{H}$ by $\phi (x,y) := (y,x)$. Then $\phi$ is an isometric isomorphism. Since $\mathcal{G}(T - \overline{\lambda} I) = \phi (\mathcal{G}(T - \overline{\lambda} I)^{-1})$ and as isomorphisms preserve closed sets it follows that $T - \overline{\lambda} I$ is closed. From here it is straightforward to show that $T$ is closed as desired. This addresses the first statement.
The second statement is that $\mathcal{R}(T - \overline{\lambda} I)$ is closed in $\mathcal{H}$ if and only if $V_{T}$ is closed. Note that $V_{T}$ is an isometric operator by Proposition 13.3(i), so in particular it is a bounded linear operator. Since a bounded linear operator is closed if and only if its domain is closed, it follows that $V_{T}$ is closed if and only if $\mathcal{D}(V_{T}) = \mathcal{R}(T - \overline{\lambda}I)$ is closed in $\mathcal{H}$. This addresses the second statement and the result follows.

Various definitions and results from the book which were used but are not contained in the original question are stated below.

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.
Definition 2.1 A complex number $\lambda$ is called a regular point for $T$ if there exists a number $c_{\lambda} > 0$ such that
\begin{equation}
\|(T-\lambda I)x \| \geq c_{\lambda} \|x\| \; \text{for all} \; x\in \mathcal{D}(T).
\end{equation}
The set of regular points of $T$ is the regularity domain of $T$ and denoted by $\pi (T)$.


Proposition 2.1 Let $T$ be a linear operator on $\mathcal{H}$, and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.
(i) $\lambda \in \pi (T)$ if and only if $T - \lambda I$ has a bounded inverse $(T - \lambda I)^{-1}$ defined on $\mathcal{R}(T - \lambda I)$. ...
...
(iv) If $T$ is closed and $\lambda \in \pi (T)$, then $\mathcal{R}(T - \lambda I)$ is a closed linear subspace of $\mathcal{H}$.


This proposition is stated under the assumptions that $T$ is a densely defined symmetric linear operator on $\mathcal{H}$, ${\rm Im} \, \lambda > 0$ and that $V_{T}$ is defined on $\mathcal{H}$ by
\begin{equation}
V_{T} = (T - \lambda I) (T - \overline{\lambda} I)^{-1} \; \text{with domain} \, \mathcal{D}(V_{T}) = \mathcal{R}(T - \overline{\lambda} I).
\end{equation}
Proposition 13.3
(i) The Cayley transform $V_{T}$ is an isometric operator on $\mathcal{H}$ with domain $\mathcal{D}(V_{T}) = \mathcal{R}(T - \overline{\lambda} I)$ and range $\mathcal{R}(V_{T}) = \mathcal{R}(T - \lambda I)$.
...
(iii) $T$ is closed if and only if $V_{T}$ is closed.
...


While trying to prove my question, I noticed that some textbooks apply those statements where $\lambda = i$ is used to define the Cayley transformation. This special case simplifies everything but, at the same time, hides how to handle the general case (which is what you did). Thank you!
